# Spring avro consumer message converter exception

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform

I have a spring cloud application. Here are consumer application properties

```
cloud:
   stream:
     default:
       producer:
         useNativeEncoding: true
       consumer:
         useNativeEncoding: true
     bindings:
       inputtest:
         destination: test
         content-type: application/*+avro
       outputtest:
         destination: test
         content-type: application/*+avro

     kafka:
       streams:
         binder:
           configuration:
             application:
               server: localhost:8082
       binder:
         producer-properties:
           key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
           value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
           schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
         consumer-properties:
           key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
           value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
           schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
           specific.avro.reader: true
       schema:
         avro:
           dynamicSchemaGenerationEnabled: true
```

And also StreamListener is also configured

```
    public void consumeDetails(GenericRecord message) {

        System.out.println(message);
    }
```

Its able to get the Genericrecord But when i put any Java class at the place of generic record its throwing an exception

```
@StreamListener(CreateMessageSink.INPUT)
    public void consumeDetails(**TestMessage** message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
```

And exception is that i am getting on receiving message is

```
org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [com.dataset.CreateMessage] to [com.notebook..TestMessge] for GenericMessage [payload={ "time": 1570614318582, "task": "Create", "userId": "-1", "status": "Success", "severity": "INFO", "details": {"notebookId": "1", "datasetId": "1"}}, headers={kafka_offset=59, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@745a009e, deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=dataset-create-test, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1570614318587, contentType=application/*+avro}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={"tenantId": "-1", "time": 1570614318582, "task": "CreateDataset", "userId": "-1", "status": "Success", "source": "dataset-svc", "severity": "INFO", "details": {"notebookId": "d02fd508-f6cc-4d2f-a713-4298bca4e216", "datasetId": "5d9dac2eb7420146d6a79d30"}}, headers={kafka_offset=59, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@745a009e, deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=dataset-create-test, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1570614318587, contentType=application/*+avro}]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.SmartPayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(SmartPayloadArgumentResolver.java:126)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:117)
```

Comment: Is the class annotated with @EnableBinding(CreateMessageSink.class) ?